# Find all non-navigating links on a page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, href

I'm working on a project where I have to find all links on page and attach an event to them.
Problem is, I have to **exclude all non-navigating links**.
e.g.
the following scenarios should be excluded

```
<a>
<a href="">
<a href="#">
<a href="#" onclick="return false;" />
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
<a href="javascript:{}">
<a href="#0">
```

The following code gets all the links and attaches event to it. But it does not exclude the above scenarios.

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
      for (let link of links) {
        if (link.href == base || (link.href.indexOf(base + '#') >= 0)) {
          console.log(' - link[' + link.href + '] is same');
        } else {
          console.log(' + link[' + link.href + '] is bindable');
          link.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            fireEvent();
          });
        }
      }
```

From my research, the closest I seem to get to achieving this is through a regular expression like:

```
 var expression = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
var regex = new RegExp(expression);
var t = link.getAttribute("href");

if (t.match(regex)) {
  alert("Successful match");
} else {
  alert("No match");
}
```

But I'm looking for a better method or an optimal solution for this. Please can you help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something along the lines of:

```
$$('a[href]:not([href^="#"]):not([href^="javascript"]):not([href=""])')
```